# Subversioning System / Changelog and Bugsubmission

Tags: web-services, svn

I am looking for a small software versioning (changelog) and bug submission system with a web-frontend.
The features I only need is a change-log where users can see what they can expect and a tiny bug-submission system. I don't need the many features SVN offers as software versiong as the project is quite small and I do all development locally.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll do just fine coding raw html with your requirements. If you can code in any language, the html you'll need is minimal it'll be easy to pick up in the case that you're not familiar with it.

Although, I do still recommend rethinking your decision not to use SVN. If your project is open source, have a look at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/), which offers free source code hosting including bug tracker, SVN repository, release management and wiki. It'll also make your project more discoverable. If it's not open source, you can purchase private hosting on [github](https://github.com/), but that uses git which is more complicated.

Comment: +1 for recommending rethinking the decision not to use SVN, or other version control system.

Comment: Its a custom C-software for internal corporate use. I use github but only on a local machine which is not pointed to the internet.

Comment: I think Mantis is what I am looking for. Ill take a closer look at that!

Answer (score 0):

[Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) is probably what you want - web based bug system that's quite nice, fast and simple. It integrates with SVN using a php page you can access using curl from a SVN hook.

We used it as a bug tracker, when the code was committed (with a special regex in the log comment) the files that were changed were added to the mantis bug as a bugnote. I'm not 100% sure of your situation, but it appears at first glance that this kind of arrangement is similar to what you want.